# Shim for FileReader() in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a shim for [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) in IE 9?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This polyfill](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) uses Flash to provide access to the filesystem on browsers that don't support the File APIs (IE and Safari), but does not support drag-n-drop.

[This one](https://github.com/MrSwitch/dropfile) uses Silverlight to allow drag-n-drop.

Comment: https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is one https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js (untested).
http://html5please.com/ is great for this kind of question.

Answer (score -7):

IE9 [doesn't support the HTML5 File API](http://caniuse.com/filereader). Of course there might be other ways to implement the feature you are trying to implement (which by the way you haven't explained).