# how to get file input in IE on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I need to get a file on load to input.
This code works in chrome, opera and firefox but not with IE:

```
$("input:file").change(function ()
{
  // Get a reference to the fileList
  var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
  // If no files were selected, or no FileReader support, return
  if ( !files.length || !window.FileReader ) return;
  // Only proceed if the selected file is an text
  if ( /^text/.test( files[0].type ) ) 
  {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText( files[0] );
    reader.onloadend = function()
    {
      restoreCSS(this.result);
    }
  }
}
```

In IE `!!this.files` return false. Thank's for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of IE are you using? [`FileReader` isn't supported in IE until version 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader).

As @apsillers commented, there's [another question asking about how to imitate `FileReader` support in browsers that don't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089897/shim-for-filereader-in-ie-9). I believe they all require some sort of plugin (Flash/Silverlight), as before the `FileReader` API, JavaScript did not have any access to the file system.

Comment: @Andrew: [Shim for FileReader() in IE 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089897/shim-for-filereader-in-ie-9)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This issue is closed.