# Internet Explorer 9 File Reader(HTML 5) Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, filereader

I am using File Reader of HTML 5 for reading csv file(uploaded by html file uploader) and it is not supported in IE(8,9).Is there any easy alternate at client side for that ?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089897/shim-for-filereader-in-ie-9