# Send ZIP file to server in Base64 via POST

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, post, base64

I'm trying to send a zip containing multiple files from the client side to the server using an ajax request.
The zip is encoded into a Base64 String in javascript and passed as a post parameter

Javascript code:

```
            var fileUp = document.getElementById("wsFile");
            var file = fileUp.files[0];

            var array = new Array();
            array = file.name.split(".");


            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            if(array[array.length-1]=="zip" && file.size<=10000000){

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "X",true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


                 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                         dojo.byId("content").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
                     }
                 }
                 reader.onload = function(){
                     var params = "file="+ reader.result+"&fileName="+file.name;
                     xhr.send(params);
                };

}
```

Server-side(Spring MVC):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/X", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String X(@RequestParam("file") String file, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName, Locale locale, Model model) {


            System.out.println(file);

            byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(file);

            System.out.println(decoded);


            File folder = new File("C:\\MTT");
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            File f = new File("C:\\MTT\\"+fileName);



try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fos.write(decoded);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So far so good, the ajax request is successful and the server receives the same Base64 String that the client sent. 
However, when I try to extract the files inside the zip, I get a corrupt archive message.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of zip archives?
Sorry for any naiveness, but I've never done this before

Comment: `"the server receives the same Base64 String that the client sent"` Does the server generate the same file from the _Base64_ ? Confirm by hashing on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through your code, I believe you're not sending what you think you're sending!

It's due to these two lines

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
// and later
var params = "file="+ reader.result+"&fileName="+file.name;
```

Consider; what does [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) actually produce? e.g.

```
var b = new Blob(['Hello World!'], {type: 'text/plain'}),
    fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function () {console.log(this.result);};
fr.readAsDataURL(b);
// data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
```

i.e. your `reader.result` is not just *Base64* data, so not exactly what you want

```
var base64Data = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);
var params = "file=" + base64Data + "&fileName=" + file.name;
```

---

Note that the *Base64* in my example is **longer** than the text it represents. This will always be true, so you might want to consider sending the file as a *binary* instead; just pass `file` directly into `send` with content type e.g. *application/octet-stream*, though this will also mean your server code would need to be changed too, for how it reacts.

Comment: I've tried the exact way you have there and, when trying to open the zip archive, I get "unexpected end of archive" and the WinRAR file explorer doesn't show any file in there

Comment: @NunoNeto see [**this demo** http://jsbin.com/ahuzas/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/ahuzas/1/edit) I just made where _JavaScript_ takes your file and gives you back a base64 dataURI link for the same file.    If you're still having problems, what you will need to do is **log what you get** so you can debug which step is not working as expected. i.e. log the base64 generated in _JavaScript_, log the Spring variable `file`, and compare the input file to the decoded file (file length, any hashes).

Comment: It may be something as simple as the server is modifying the received data in an attempt to decode the "form data", so to fix it, in _JavaScript_ you do `window.encodeURIComponent(base64Data)`

Comment: 3rd comment in a row -- Of course, I'm assuming you're trying to do all this on [a browser that supports _FileReader_](http://caniuse.com/filereader). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089897/shim-for-filereader-in-ie-9

Comment: I trying it in chrome and I'm also checking to see if the browser suports FileReader. I've already tried your solution, except for the window.encodeURIComponent(base64Data), but I'll give it another go and see if a more thorough approach yields any results
Thanks anyways ;)

Comment: I've worked out that there are in fact differences in the Base64 string between the one in js and the one received in java. Most are stuff like the '+' char being replaced with ' ' and others alike. I've found a page documenting this only in C (https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/wiki/WebSafeBase64).
Any one has an ideia on how to go about solving this? I've yet to foudn any solution

Comment: Thanks alot, I had already tried window.encodeURIComponent(base64Data) but had forgot to use URLDecoder.decode(file) (which btw is deprecated, have to find a better alternative) to convert it back to a propor Base64 String

Answer (score 0):

I believe for sending the zip file , OCTET stream should be used as content-type.  Another problem in your code is that you are just taking the file name as the input. But to receive a file you should have the inputstream for the file. Also you should send the file contents and not just the name of the file.

If you need to send multiple form params with you request such as file metadata and actual file contents, then using Multipart/form or Multipart/mixed content types should be considered.

Here is a good tutorial for sending files using jersey framework. No matter what framework you are using, but you can take the learnings from the example:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: They're sending a _String_, not a _zip_

Comment: @PaulS. Yeah that another problem I am trying to mention in my edited answer. Edits in progress :-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan I could be wrong but by encoding the zip into base64, am I not sending the entire zip content, including its files?
I'm also sending the file name to make it easy to save with the original name